# Flutter video_player cannot load multiple videos in one page

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-video-player, video-player

I want to create a page in Flutter with multiple looping videos. On my phone (which is a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Plus) all the videos are loading perfectly, but when I run the same app on other phones (I tried on a Samsung Galaxy S6 and Galaxy A71) 2 videos are loading and the other ones are replaced with [black squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXZSL.jpg).

This is my `flutter doctor -v` run:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.630], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (2 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2) 
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java       
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A715F (mobile) • R58N70XS23W • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
```

(I write my code in Visual Studio Code)

I don't get any errors in the debug version of the application but the videos are still not loading.

This is the configuration for the video_player controller:

```dart
class clipVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;
  clipVideo(this.path);
  @override
  _clipVideo createState() => _clipVideo();
}

class _clipVideo extends State<clipVideo> {
  String _path;
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _path = widget.path;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(_path);
    //_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
    //   'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _controller.play();
    _controller.setVolume(0.0);
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the content of my Scaffold of the page where I want to render multiple looping videos:

```dart
body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Column(
              children: [
                Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/logoecomed.png'),
                    width: 200.0),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff40514e),
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Nurom',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 15.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 30.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record1.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff40514e),
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Nurom',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record3.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record2.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record6.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record4.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text?',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff40514e),
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Nurom',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      'Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff40514e),
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 40.0)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 550,
                  child: clipVideo('assets/videos/record5.mp4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                // Center(
                //     child: Flexible(
                //         child: Text(
                //   'Text',
                //   textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                //   style: TextStyle(
                //     color: Color(0xff40514e),
                //     fontSize: 18.0,
                //     fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                //   ),
                // ))),
                // SizedBox(
                //   height: 90,
                // )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )))
```

the assets are included in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/logoecomed.png
    - assets/videos/record1.mp4
    - assets/videos/record2.mp4
    - assets/videos/record3.mp4
    - assets/videos/record4.mp4
    - assets/videos/record5.mp4
    - assets/videos/record6.mp4
```

I changed the video_player version to a newer one, but it didn't solve anything.Is it maybe because of the phones? Are the videos too big? (every `record[number].mp4` has between 8 - 10 MB).

Edit: I tried to reduce the size of the videos to 2-3 MB and it still doesn't work. But I discovered that when I enter into that page with multiple videos, the video_player plugin freezes/crashes (I have another video on the previous page that freezed also), so the plugin crashes somewhere

Second Edit: after more `flutter run`s, I found something here:

```
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): AssumedSupport [sizeAndRate.rotated, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.google.h264.decoder, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): AssumedSupport [sizeAndRate.rotated, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): AssumedSupport [sizeAndRate.rotated, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.google.h264.decoder, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
D/MediaCodecInfo(18771): AssumedSupport [sizeAndRate.rotated, 1080x2280x60.19792938232422] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [zeroflte, SM-G920F, samsung, 24]
```

and I think this is an issue with the videos and not the player

Third edit: After cropping and resizing the videos, the video_player show only the first frame of every video except the last one. I don t know what to do about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after all.. Downgrading the video_player plugin and resizing the videos have done the thing.

Answer (score 0):

First Change this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
```

Build and run the app again. If it doesn't work then run the below commands on the Terminal.

```
flutter upgrade

flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"

flutter doctor -v
```

then if the issue still persists then just shift to the beta channel and the upgrade flutter then it will fix it.

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

I am asking you run Terminal Commands because of this error I noticed.

```
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
```

Let me Know if it works..

**Note:** After running the Terminal Commands you need to build app again and run.

Comment: The issue is not solved, but now I see that for some reason, `video_player` chooses randomly a video from that ListView to play and the other videos are just dark green or black squares